# Firestore listener fires two changes on adding new item to list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When adding a new record to a list in a firestore database, listener fires two different changes, one for ***removed*** item! and another one for ***added***.
I assume that it should fires only change type: ***added***, right?

I've figured out that, it just acts like that only when `limit()` is provided on query reference.

Here's a snippet with `limit()`:

```html
<button>Add a record</button>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  // config
  firebase.initializeApp({ projectId: "digforbug" });
  let db = firebase.firestore();

  // Add new
  document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
    db.collection('posts').add({ date: Date.now() });
  }

  // Listen to changes
  db.collection('posts').limit(1).onSnapshot((s)=>{
    s.docChanges().forEach(function(change){ console.log(change.type, change.doc.id) })
  });
</script>
```

And here's a snippet without `limit()`:

```html
<button>Add a record</button>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  // config
  firebase.initializeApp({ projectId: "digforbug" });
  let db = firebase.firestore();

  // Add new
  document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
    db.collection('posts').add({ date: Date.now() });
  }

  // Listen to changes
  db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((s)=>{
    s.docChanges().forEach(function(change){ console.log(change.type, change.doc.id) })
  });
</script>
```

It's absolutely affecting the UI when listener remove a list item to add another one!

So, Why should it fires change type ***removed*** before ***added*** when using `limit()`, and how to come over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour as explained hereafter.

Preamble: By default, Firestore document are sorted in the collection **by their ID**.

The first time a doc is added to the collection, your listener detects it with an `change` of type `added`.

The second time you add a doc, there are two possible cases:

1. The new doc is sorted **BEFORE** the previous one in the collection. Since the query is limited to one doc, the previous one is removed from the query and the next one is added to the query. Hence the behaviour you notice: first a `change` of type `removed`, then a `change` of type `added`.
2. The new doc is sorted **AFTER** the previous one in the collection. Nothing happens in the listener, since the first doc in the collection is still the previous one and therefore the query still returns the previous doc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I think solution is still missing, I have a social web app which append and remove posts on UI depending on their doc id, so when listener fires a `removed` change type, post should disappear. So how to keep the old post appearing and just append the new added post ?!

Comment: "So how to keep the old post appearing and just append the new added post ?" If you want to show several posts you need to increase the limit accordingly. Also you probably want to sort them by date, like you had initially done in your question. Note that there is no way to change the behaviour of the listener: it’s up to you to use (to "play with") `change.type` to make your front end working as you wish.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadSaleh, if my answer helped you please upvote and possibly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Renaud